# When updating an image, binary data seams to be truncated

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm at my wit's end here trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. My goal is to simply rotate a image 90 degrees and save the changed full image back to the file system and then update a thumbnail version in the database. The file system image is changed appropriately however when the image is saved back to the database it seams only the first 28 characters are saved. SQL reports no errors.

Any ideas on what I've done wrong here would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
    Image image = Image.FromFile(image_path);
    image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
    image.Save(image_path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    Byte[] thumbnail = null;
    System.Drawing.Image thumb = image.GetThumbnailImage(72, 47, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
    thumbnail = imageToByteArray(thumb);
    image.Dispose();

        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MY_DATABASE"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conn);
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
        sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
        sqlComm.CommandText = @"UPDATE MY_TABLE SET pic='@thumbnail' WHERE pic_id= cast(@pic_id As Int) ";
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@thumbnail", SqlDbType.Image, thumbnail.Length).Value = thumbnail;
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@pic_id", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@pic_id"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(pic_id);
        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            Int32 rowsAffected = sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            context.Response.Write("rowsAffected:" + rowsAffected + "<br/>");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        //sqlConn.Open();
        //sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();

        context.Response.BinaryWrite(thumbnail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MY_TABLE SET pic='@thumbnail'

Looks suspicious, why the quotes?

At a guess, I'd say you are overwriting the header in the bitmap, with whatever bit pattern the string "@thumbnail" equates to corresponds to your setting a length of "28" in the header.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format